# How do I click on a button rendered with the function using react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

[Here is My Code
(https://hizliresim.com/gPmJDO)

Here is My Error
(https://hizliresim.com/dLYAaD)

Comment: can you provide actual code so we can take a better look ?

Comment: @Yasin DALKILIÇ check this - https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-my-function-being-called-every-time-the-component-renders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a handler function as arrow function.

```
  handleClick = () => {
      alert("Test Alert");
    }
```

An then call it

```
renderGridItem = ({ item }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.handleClick()}>
      ....
      ...
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

You don.t need to bind if you use handler function as an arrow function.

Comment: Using an arrow function in render creates a new function each time the component renders, which may break optimizations based on strict identity comparison.

Comment: Yes, but the scope of that function will be for render method only.

Answer (score 0):

Without binding your function to a component instance, make them as arrow functions

```
handleClick = () => {
  alert("test");
};

renderGridItem = ({ item }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleClick}>
      ...
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.